# Tile window to the top does not work

Tags: xubuntu

### Tile window to the top does not work on either Super+8 or Super+Up(Keypad).
The others still work well.
What should be done next ?

OS: Xubuntu 21.10 x86_64
Host: HP Laptop 14-ck0xxx
Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic
Packages: 1691 (dpkg), 10 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.1.8
Resolution: 1366x768, 2560x1080
DE: Xfce 4.16
WM: Xfwm4
WM Theme: Greybird
Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3]
Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/
Terminal: xfce4-terminal
Terminal Font: Monospace 12